# Change Font Style by Option Dropdown Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a test for making text style changing with combobox with Javascript and CSS. but, i just find font type changing in this site and i got nothing from google. and this is my code :

```js
var changeFont = function(font) {
  console.log(font.value)
  document.getElementById("output-text").style.fontFamily = font.value;
}
```

```css
.tebal {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.miring {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: italic;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="windows-1252">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src=”https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js”></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h3>Text Style Changed with combobox</h3>
</div>

<div class="text-center" id="output-text">
  Hello Guys
</div>

<div class="text-center">
  <select id="input-font" class="input" onchange="changeFont (this);">
    <option value="Times New Roman" selected="selected">Times New Roman</option>
    <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="algerian">Algerian</option>
    <option value="berlin sans fb">Berlin Sans FB</option>
    <option value="bold" class="bold">Tebal</option>
    <option value="miring" class="miring">Miring</option>
    <option value="" class="">Style1</option>
    <option value="" class="">Style2</option>
    <option value="" class="">Style3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

i want make it like this[This (Photo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeHvx.png) 
every i change style from combo box, style text it will change but i cant find the example how to make it and what is the problem from my code. please help me for solve this code :(, thanks.

Note : this is the translate From my photo
 -  ini text berubah sesuai css = this text changes according to css
 - tebal = Bold
 - Miring = Italic
 - bingkai = Frame

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be more simple to define the class for each font. then put the class name to the option value. With this, it will be more flexible if you need to add another style to your text (not only font-family, but you can add color or anything else to the class)
Here is the example with your case

```js
var changeFont = function(font) {
  console.log(font.value)
  document.getElementById("output-text").className = "text-center " + font.value;
}
```

```css
.bold {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.miring {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: blue;
  font-style: italic;
}

.Arial{
  font-family: Arial;
}
.Algerian{
  font-family: Algerian;
}
.Berlin-sans-fb{
  font-family: 'Berlin sans fb';
}
.Times-new-roman{
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="windows-1252">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src=”https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js”></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h3>Text Style Changed with combobox</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center" id="output-text">
    Hello Guys
  </div>

  <div class="text-center">
    <select id="input-font" class="input" onchange="changeFont (this);">
      <option value="Times-new-roman" selected="selected">Times New Roman</option>
      <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
      <option value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
      <option value="Berlin-sans-fb">Berlin Sans FB</option>
      <option value="bold" class="bold">Tebal</option>
      <option value="miring" class="miring">Miring</option>
      <option value="" class="">Style1</option>
      <option value="" class="">Style2</option>
      <option value="" class="">Style3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use className instead if you are looking to attach a bunch of styles.

So for example, in your script tag you can add:

```
document.getElementById("output-text").className = font.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try an if statement? And I think you need innerHTML.

```
var changeFont = function(font) {
if (font === "tebal") {
document.getElementById("output-text").innerHTML = "You have selected Tebal!";
} else if (font === miring) {
document.getElementById("output-text").innerHTML = "You have selected Miring!";
} else...
```

Edit: Ah, looks like I read your question wrong. Though you can still use the loop for changing styles!